# How force WebExtension update on start browser?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest, opera-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

How force (or request in installation) WebExtension update on start browser?

In Firefox I need click in this option:

[image: Firefox]

In Opera I need click in this button:

[image]

What I want to know is if there is any way to check using the API if there is any update or configure "manifest.json" to do this.

I need add autoupdate to Opera, Firefox and Chrome.

My current manifest.json (Firefox):

```
{
    "name": "Name",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Description",
    "applications": {
        "gecko": {
            "id": "xxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxx.org",
            "strict_min_version": "45.0"
        }
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "images/icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },
    "icons": {
        "128": "images/icon-128px.png",
        "48":  "images/icon-48px.png",
        "32":  "images/icon-32px.png",
        "16":  "images/icon.png"
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-requestUpdateCheck

Answer (score 0):

For chrome extension, you could use [`chrome.runtime.requestUpdateCheck`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-requestUpdateCheck) to request an immediate update check, and please be aware of the following important tips.

> **Important**: Most extensions/apps should not use this method, since **chrome already does automatic checks every few hours**, and you can listen for the [`runtime.onUpdateAvailable`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onUpdateAvailable) event without needing to call `requestUpdateCheck`.
>
> This method is only appropriate to call in very limited circumstances, such as if your extension/app talks to a backend service, and the backend service has determined that the client extension/app version is very far out of date and you'd like to prompt a user to update. Most other uses of `requestUpdateCheck`, such as calling it unconditionally based on a repeating timer, probably only serve to waste client, network, and server resources.